# Need to understand how to use `GROUP BY` in SQL Queries

Tags: sql, group-by

Below is the sql query I wrote and result, I need two sql queries to get below last two outputs.

Query:

```
select 
    t2.VoucherNumber as Invoice_Number, 
    i.ItemName as Item_Name, 
    t2.Aqty as Qty
from Item i, Party p, Tran1 t1, VTran2 t2, Cases c, VoucherTypes VT
Where t1.LorryNo='22-8205' 
    and t1.VoucherType=VT.VoucherType 
    and VT.ActualVoucherType='sales'
    and t1.VoucherNumber=t2.VoucherNumber 
    and t2.ItemName=i.Itemname 
    and t2.ItemName=c.ItemName 
    and t1.LoadingStatus='2'
GROUP BY t2.VoucherNumber, i.ItemName, t2.Aqty
```

Result (This is wrong):

```
     Invoice_Number Item_Name   Qty
      001               A       36.00
      001               B       10.00
      001               B       60.00
      002               A       100.00
```

Expect Result from first query (This is I need, sum qty by same itemName in same invoice no):

```
     Invoice_Number Item_Name   Qty
      001               A       36.00
      001               B       70.00
      002               A       100.00
```

By the way, I'm also looking for another query, with this expected result :

```
Item_Name   Qty
      A     136.00
      B     70.00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First query, use a sum on qty, group by voucherNumber and itemname

```
select 
    t2.VoucherNumber as Invoice_Number, 
    i.ItemName as Item_Name, 
    SUM(t2.Aqty) as Qty
from Item i, Party p, Tran1 t1, VTran2 t2, Cases c, VoucherTypes VT
Where t1.LorryNo='22-8205' 
    and t1.VoucherType=VT.VoucherType 
    and VT.ActualVoucherType='sales'
    and t1.VoucherNumber=t2.VoucherNumber 
    and t2.ItemName=i.Itemname 
    and t2.ItemName=c.ItemName 
    and t1.LoadingStatus='2'
GROUP BY t2.VoucherNumber, i.ItemName
```

second query also, but group by the only field you need (and remove VoucherNumber from select clause)

```
select 

    i.ItemName as Item_Name, 
    sum(st2.Aqty) as Qty
from Item i, Party p, Tran1 t1, VTran2 t2, Cases c, VoucherTypes VT
Where t1.LorryNo='22-8205' 
    and t1.VoucherType=VT.VoucherType 
    and VT.ActualVoucherType='sales'
    and t1.VoucherNumber=t2.VoucherNumber 
    and t2.ItemName=i.Itemname 
    and t2.ItemName=c.ItemName 
    and t1.LoadingStatus='2'
GROUP BY  i.ItemName
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to exclude the aggregated column (Qty) from the `GROUP BY` clause at the end of the query.

The `GROUP BY` syntax is quite simple - you need to SELECT the columns you wish to group on, and apply an aggregate function like SUM, COUNT, MAX etc to the column(s) you wish to aggregate.

e.g. in your case:

```
SELECT
    t2.VoucherNumber as Invoice_Number, 
    i.ItemName as Item_Name, 
    SUM(t2.Aqty) as Qty
FROM ...
WHERE...
GROUP BY t2.VoucherNumber, i.ItemName; -- Do not group by the aggregated column
```

And without Voucher:

```
SELECT
    i.ItemName as Item_Name, 
    SUM(t2.Aqty) as Qty
FROM ...
WHERE...
GROUP BY i.ItemName; -- Do not group by the aggregated column
```